# Find shortest path with OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying to find the shortest path with the above code:

```
List<ODocument> spath = orientGraph.getRawGraph().query(new OSQLSynchQuery<Object>(
            "select flatten(shortestPath("+v1+","+v2+",'BOTH').out)"));
```

As I understand this will return a list of the edges. But when I print the results I get this

> [#-2:0 v0]

What does it mean? Also, I wonder if there will be problems with this function because of the lightweight edges. (I had confront a similar issue when I was trying to use the getVertices() function)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
select expand( out ) from ( select shortestPath("+v1+","+v2+",'BOTH') )
```

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to run forever. I have 105,000 nodes and 2,000,000 edges. What is the approximately execution time?

Comment: Depends how your node are connected, your HW/SW configuration and your settings. How much takes only this: select shortestPath("+v1+","+v2+",'BOTH') ?

Comment: What's your hw/sw cfg?

Comment: I don't have any special configuration. I load the data with this [code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:39e8) and trying to find the shortest path with this [code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:39e9)

Comment: hw/sw config means what Hardware do you have in terms of CPU/RAM/Disk and for SW means what OS do you have and what version of OrientDB

Comment: I have a 2.3 Ghz CPU (i5), 4GB RAM and 320GB disk. I running on Macintosh OSX Mavericks (10.9) and i use orientdb-1.6.2

Comment: Are you using a remote or local/plocal URL? If remote, please assure the cache is enabled on server. Open bin/server.sh/.bat and set this: -Dcache.level2.enabled=true -Dcache.level2.size=-1 -Dcache.level1.enabled=true -Dcache.level1.size=-1

Comment: No I am using local URL

Comment: I am still unable to find the shortest path. Is it possible the lightweight edges cause the problem? I am asking because I encounter this problem when I wanted to use countEdges() function.

Comment: countEdges() doesn't work with Lightweight edges. Why do you use it?

Comment: I know that it doesn't work. So I stop using it. I just wonder if there is some similar issue with my case now, because I haven't succeed to yet to find the shortest path